# ¿Qué funcion comprueba si existe un elemento dentro de un array? PHP

Tags: php

tengo este array y una variable como ejemplo:

```
$parametro = 'age';

$arr = ['bebe' => 'Bob', 'age' => 23, 'too' => 23 ];
```

¿Qué función de PHP puede validar si el array tiene alguna llave igual que el valor de la variable $name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si necesitas comprobar la existencia dentro de un elemento (key) en un array puedes utilizar la función "array_key_exists", En tu caso:

```
array_key_exists('age', $arr);
```

Comment: Esa estoy utilzando ahora mismo, la encontré de este doc: [enlace](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array.php) Ya que realmente necesito buscar por llaves y no por valores del array

Answer (score 1):

La funcion isset verifica eso, prueba con `isset($arr[$name]);`

Comment: isset funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

`array_search` Busca un valor determinado en un array y devuelve la primera clave correspondiente en caso de éxito

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => 'azul', 1 => 'rojo', 2 => 'verde', 3 => 'rojo');

$clave = array_search('verde', $array); // $clave = 2;
$clave = array_search('rojo', $array);  // $clave = 1;
?>
```

Comment: Es correcto, pero en vez de valor.. ¿Cómo lo haría con la llave?

Comment: Da igual como crea el arreglo, seguira siendo un array