# Depende el arreglo que me llega al controlador hacer una cosa u otra

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hola estoy guardando la edición de un pedido en mi base de datos. Pero según el pedido puede llevar o más campos o menos. Por ejemplo este es un tipo de fila de pedido:

```
array:16 [
  "dato0" => "Grinde normal mayorista"
  "precio" => "15"
  "cantidad" => "1"
  "subtotal" => "15"
  "idCliente" => "16"
  "nombre" => "Mario Vizcaino Gonzalez"
  "dni" => "53424234"
  "idProducto" => "42"
  "envio" => "0.00"
  "ticket" => "202010029"
  "factura" => null
  "metodo" => "transferencia"
  "estado" => "0"
  "sms" => null
  "entrega" => "9"
  "facturacion" => "9"
]
```

Y este otro tipo:

```
array:18 [
  "dato0" => "Papel de fumara mayorista"
  "dato1" => "48"  /*campo extra*/
  "precio" => "3.5"
  "cantidad" => "1"
  "subtotal" => "3.5"
  "idCliente" => "16"
  "nombre" => "Mario Vizcaino Gonzalez"
  "dni" => "53424234"
  "idProducto" => "41"
  "idCombination" => "48" /*campo extra*/
  "envio" => "0.00"
  "ticket" => "202010029"
  "factura" => null
  "metodo" => "transferencia"
  "estado" => "0"
  "sms" => null
  "entrega" => "9"
  "facturacion" => "9"
]
```

Este tipo de array puede ir en un mismo pedido, según el producto que escojen.

Estoy intentando hacer así, pero no funciona:

```
$actPedido = new Order;
            
  $actPedido->id_cliente = $arraySingle['idCliente'];
  $actPedido->cliente = $arraySingle['nombre'];
  $actPedido->dni = $arraySingle['dni'];
  $actPedido->idProducto = $arraySingle['idProducto'];
  $actPedido->producto = $arraySingle['dato0'];
    if(!is_null($arraySingle['dato1'])) {
       $actPedido->idCombination = $arraySingle['dato1']; 
    }
    if(!is_null($arraySingle['dato1'])) {
       $nombreCombination = Combination::where('id', $arraySingle['dato1'])->first();
       $str = substr($nombreCombination->combination, 13);
       $namePro = ucfirst($str);
       $actPedido->opcion = str_replace("-"," ",$namePro);
    }
```

Si todos los productos son del tipo array 2 me lo hace sin problema. El problema es cuando el pedido lleva solo como el array 1 o mezclado que me devuelve este error:

```
"Undefined index: dato1"
```

Comment: Tienes dos `if` con la misma condición?

Comment: Si es por que estube haciendo pruebas, pero no afecta nada a lo que comento

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué funcion comprueba si existe un elemento dentro de un array? PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167523/qu%c3%a9-funcion-comprueba-si-existe-un-elemento-dentro-de-un-array-php)

Comment: Intentaste con `isset($arraySingle['dato1'])`?

Comment: Si correcto con el `isset` todo solucionado. Gracias a los dos, si poneis una respuesta la marco